# Building Qt 5.2: Should I use ActivePerl or strawbery perl?

Tags: c++, perl, build, qt5

I want to build Qt 5.2 on a Windows 8.1 system for the target platform x64 using Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

The qt configure and build process depends on perl. My question is: Should I use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) or [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)?

Does one of them provide any advantages when building Qt?

Comment: The point of Strawberry Perl is that it includes a complete C compiler toolchain, which allows you to install almost any CPAN module. ActiveState offers a selection of precompiled modules for its distribution instead. Considering that you only need it to run Configure, any distribution would do – they're essentially both the same Perl implementation with different branding. Of course I'd rather use Strawberry, but I can understand why a company might decide otherwise.

Comment: I've no idea whether there are any "advantages", but currently only ActiveState is tested, not Strawberry. So all other things considered equal, I'd just use ActiveState because it's known to work.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Get_The_Source says: "In addition you need to have Perl installed. This is standard on most Linux distributions and Mac OS X. Windows users can download ActivePerl [activestate.com] for free. If you also want to build Qt/WebKit from sources, you will need to install Python as well. Windows users can download ActivePython [activestate.com] for free."
@peppe Seems that the official way to build Qt is to use ActivePerl and ActivePython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qt-project.org/wiki/Get_The_Source says: "In addition you need to have Perl installed. This is standard on most Linux distributions and Mac OS X. Windows users can download ActivePerl [activestate.com] for free. If you also want to build Qt/WebKit from sources, you will need to install Python as well. Windows users can download ActivePython [activestate.com] for free."

Seems that the official way to build Qt is to use ActivePerl and ActivePython

Answer (score 1):

I've used Strawberry Perl with Qt 5.1 and it was good (I've compiled Qt from git repositories).